# Spark claims resources not available when they are available

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark UI running with 3 workers

```
Worker Id                                            Address           State    Cores        Memory Resources
worker-20220824124633-192.168.191.141-34525     192.168.191.141:34525   DEAD    6 (0 Used)  6.7 GiB (0.0 B Used)    
worker-20220824125307-192.168.191.141-44971     192.168.191.141:44971   DEAD    6 (2 Used)  6.7 GiB (1024.0 MiB Used)   
worker-20220824130742-192.168.191.141-46371     192.168.191.141:46371   ALIVE   6 (2 Used)  6.7 GiB (1024.0 MiB Used)
```

This is my pyspark code. I am trying to read a parquet file of size 111 KB.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://master:7077")\
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet("userdata1.parquet")
```

I am scheduling my job with the following configuration:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("etcjob")\
    .set("spark.cores.max", "2")
```

Even though spark clearly has 4 more cores free on the worker **worker-20220824130742-192.168.191.141-46371** I keep getting this message

> 22/08/24 18:10:03 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; >check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

When I run the code the worker screen displays this information

```
 Running Executors (1)
ExecutorID  State   Cores   Memory       Resources  
13          RUNNING     2   1024.0 MiB      

Job Detials
 ID: app-20220824131220-0013
 Name: etcjob
 User: myuser

Logs
stdout stderr
```

It is clear that enough memory and resources are present. Still, Spark keeps claiming resources are not available. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you run your spark application? On Yarn? On K8S? Did you set in the configuration that both driver and executor can be launched at the same worker?

Comment: I have a master working on a Ubuntu VM. I am trying to run a job from my local machine.